# Helm escape string in nested json

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I am using helm to deploy apps on kubernetes. And I'm trying to figure out how to include an escaped multiline string in a nested json generated in a kubernetes secret.

The goal is to inline a certificate provided in helm chart values in nested json (for dev. purposes only)

*Example values.yaml*

```yaml
certificate: |
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  ...
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
  ...
  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What I tried:

*configmap.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
stringData:
  vaultfile.json: |-
    [
      {
        "key": "myapp-config",
        "value": "{\"certificate\": {{ .Values.certificate | quote | quote }} }"
      }
    ]
```

Expected result:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
stringData:
  vaultfile.json: |-
    [
      {
        "key": "myapp-config",
        "value": "{\"certificate\": \"escaped-certificate\\ngoes\\nhere\"}"
      }
    ]
```

What I got:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "myapp-config",
    "value": "{\"certificate\": "\"escaped-certificate\\ngoes\\nhere\"" }"
  }
]
```

I am opened to any suggestions on how it could be done differently. But I have 2 constraints to respect:

- This chart will be used as a subchart of a parent chart that won't be edited by users (making it difficult to provide certificate as a file)
- Configuration format depends on an external tool and can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Helm contains a [`toJson` template function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#tojson-musttojson) that can convert an arbitrary object to JSON.  That will handle all of the string quoting and quote escaping that's necessary.

In the final structure:

- The value of `vaultfile.json` is a JSON-encoded string.
- Its value is a list.
- The list contains a single object, with `"key"` and `"value"` fields.
- The `"value"` is itself a JSON-encoded string.
- That innermost string has an object, with key `"certificate"` and the value being the certificate.

You can build up this structure using `toJson`, along with [`dict`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dict) and [`list`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) to create mappings and lists.  That would roughly look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata: { ... }
{{- $certObj := dict "certificate" .Values.certificate -}}
{{- $certStr := toJson $certObj -}}
{{- $kvp := "key" "myapp-config" "value" $certStr -}}
{{- $kvps := list $kvp -}}
data:
  vaultfile.json: {{ $kvps | toJson | b64enc }}
```